# Why new error appears at the next coding line when putting a comma at the end of a certain line?

Tags: python, loops, syntax

I'm quite new with coding. I need your help.
I did an exercise and hit the error. The code is like this:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):  
    if len(s)!=len(t):        
        return False
    else:    
        list_t = sorted(list(set(t))
        list_s = sorted(list(set(s))
        if list_s != list_t:            
            return False
        else:
            i=0
            j=[]
            k=[]
            for i in range len(list_s):
                j.append(list_s.count(list_s[i]))
                k.append(list_t.count(list_t[i]))
                i=i+1
                if j!=k:
                    return False
                else:                      
                      return True
```

And I get this error

```
 File "<ipython-input-43-5ac86c9b9c40>", line 7
    list_s = sorted(list(set(s))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I put a comma at the end of 5th line, then I receive a new error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-44-6a66b63cb96e>", line 8
    if list_s != list_t:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Help me to understand why I made those two errors.

Comment: You're not correctly closing your brackets in the code. sorted(list(set(s has three open brackets, and you only close with two. When you add the comma, it's looking for another piece of information inside the brackets, which never comes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically:

```
(1
```

The parser is looking for `)` and doesn't find it and instead reports a number of different errors depending on what it finds instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses in your code:

- You did not close the parentheses for `sorted`- it should be `list_t = sorted(list(set(t)))` As @Dan D. mentioned, your program is looking for a closing parentheses. When it got another letter instead, it returns a series of syntax errors
- [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) is a function, so you need `for i in range (len(list_s)):`

This code should compile correctly:

```
def isAnagram(s,t):  
    if len(s)!=len(t):        
        return False
    else:    
        list_t = sorted(list(set(t))) # add missing parenthesis
        list_s = sorted(list(set(s))) # add missing parenthesis
        if list_s != list_t:            
            return False
        else:
            i=0
            j=[]
            k=[]
            for i in range(len(list_s)): # add missing parenthesis
                j.append(list_s.count(list_s[i]))
                k.append(list_t.count(list_t[i]))
                i=i+1
                if j!=k:
                    return False
                else:                      
                    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

**First you miss ')' for sorted function and second you have whitespace on range function and you miss '()' for that  **

```
def isAnagram(s,t):

    if len(s)!=len(t):        
        return False
    else:    
        list_t = sorted(list(set(t)))
        list_s = sorted(list(set(s)))
        if list_s != list_t:            
            return False
        else:
            i = 0
            j = []
            k = []
            for i in range(len(list_s)):
                j.append(list_s.count(list_s[i]))
                k.append(list_t.count(list_t[i]))
                i=i+1
                if j!=k:
                    return False
                else:                      
                      return True
```